# How was there an extra particle in the early universe?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, antimatter, cp-violation, baryogenesis

According to theories.. In the early universe.. There were particles and anti-particles in equal number.. But there seems to be one extra particle against the number of anti-particles.. As the theories say... But how did that extra particle come from.. Because from the photons equal number of particles and anti particles were produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common hypothesis supposes that there is a slight asymetry in a transformation (i.e., slightly more likely in one direction than the other), which is called the "violating CP symmetry" (occuring in the weak interaction). See wikipedia ["baryon asymmetry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry) and ["CP violation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation).